# Java thread execution time not consistent

Tags: multithreading

im just experimenting with multithreading where im filling an array with random numbers and comparing how long it takes with two threads and one thread. thing is that the time for the first thread is much longer than the second.

code:

```
class createList extends Thread
{
    int[] array = new int[25000000];

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 25000000; i++)
        {
            array[i] = randomNumber();
        }
    }

    public static int randomNumber()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextInt(50);
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        createList listcreator1 = new createList();
        createList listcreator2 = new createList();

        listcreator1.start();
        listcreator2.start();

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        listcreator1.run();
        System.out.println(sw.elapsedTime());

        Stopwatch sw3 = new Stopwatch();
        listcreator2.run();
        System.out.println(sw3.elapsedTime());

        Stopwatch sw2 = new Stopwatch();
        int[] array = new int[50000000];
        for (int i = 0; i < 50000000; i++)
        {
            array[i] = randomNumber();
        }
        System.out.println(sw2.elapsedTime());


    }

    public static int randomNumber()
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        return random.nextInt(50);
    }
}
```

and the console output is
   5.024,
            0.945,
            1.889

what is the reason for the large difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually on the first measurement you have calculation run 3 times. You have started 2 threads in the background (by using 'start' method) and 1 on current thread (by method 'run'). Run doesn't create new thread. Just execute operation on current on, it's simple method execution.

Other measurements execute without any jobs in the background so that's way they finish faster.